# If my teacher ask me this, which is the right way to answer it?

Tags: questions, ellipsis, responses

Q : Are these books borrowed by you yesterday?

A1 : Yes, these books are.

A2 : Yes, these are.

What is difference between A1 and A2?

Comment: The question is dubious. It should have been *Were these books...*

Comment: @JanDoggen  or *"Are these the books ..."*

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are awkward. The best and simplest way to answer the question is:

> Yes.

If you need a short sentence answer, you should use one of the subject pronouns (it, he, they), not a demonstrative pronoun (this, that, these, those)

> Yes, they are.

You would use "these" to point to a particular group of books.

> Yes. These books I borrowed yesterday, but the ones in my bag I took out last week.

The difference between A1 and A2 is that in A1 the word "These" is a determiner, and in A2 it is a pronoun.